# jQuery: Finding an element

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble with this little thing. I have a code that looks like this:

```
<table>.........
    <td>
        <span class="editable" id="name"><?= $name ?></span>
        <img class="edit_field" src="icons/edit.png"/>
    </td>
....... 
</table>
```

I want to obtain the id of the span, so that I can then change it (for example add an input box in it).

I have this:

```
$('.edit_field').live('click', function() {
    var td = $(this).parent();
    var span = td.find(".editable");
    alert(span.id)
});
```

But it's not working... Any ideas? (I'm trying to do it like this so it's reusable)

Comment: unless you need the parent object, you could shorten your code a bit by doing `var span = $(this).siblings('.editable')`.  Also, consider switching to `.on` as `.live` has been deprecated

Comment: Your code should work as-is regardless of whether or not it is valid (i suspect you have duplicate id's, but that shouldn't break the above code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this http://jsfiddle.net/VPvSD/

```
$('table').on('click', '.edit_field', function() {
    var td = $(this).parent();
    var span = $(this).prev('span');
    alert(span.attr("id"));
});
```

Comment: Thanks! First line is not needed though (I mean var td = $(this).parent() )

Comment: Note for the inexperienced: "inside a table always use `<tr>` and preferably `<tbody>` "

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `live()`, because it has been deprecated. Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) with jQuery 1.7+ for delegate event handling.

```
$('table tbody').on('click', '.edit_field', function() {
    var img = $(this) ;
    var td = img.parent();   // parent td ( if needed )
    var span = img.prev('span');  // previous span ( a jQuery object )
    alert( span.attr('id') ); // or span[0].id,here span[0] will gives an element
});
```

If your `.edit_field` is not dynamically generated the use:

```
$('.edit_field').on('click', function() {
    var img = $(this) ;
    var td = img.parent();   // parent td ( if needed 
    var span = img.prev('span');  // previous span ( a jQuery object )
    alert( span.attr('id') ); // or span[0].id,here span[0] will gives an element
});
```

### Note

Don't use same `id` for multiple element. I assume that, you `span` on each row have `id=name`. If that's true, then use `class` instead of `id`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
  $('.edit_field').bind('click', function() {
   var td_id = $(this).parents('td').attr('id');
   alert(td_id);
  });
```

It would be better if you use ID rather than class :

```
  $('#name').bind('click', function() {
   var td_id = $(this).parents('td').attr('id');
   alert(td_id);
  });
```

If you need to add some html content on it, then:

```
  $('.edit_field').bind('click', function() {
   var added_html = "<input type='text' />";
   var td_id = $(this).parents('td').attr('id');
   $('#'+td_id).html(added_html);
   alert(td_id);
  });
```

For this case, instead live, its better to use bind or on.